# Is it possible / practical to use a directional speaker as a "sound flashlight"?

Tags: biomedical-engineering, ultrasound, sound

E.g. use the direction the sound is coming from and the intensity to tell where the object is located at, and the frequency to tell the color of whatever this "flashlight" is pointing at (e.g. attach a camera to it, red is 600, 800 and 900Hz)?

Just an idea I thought about, if I try to build it I'll post the thing online

Comment: are you asking about echolocation? ... what do you mean by `color`?

Comment: Have a look at the [Fluke ii900 Acoustic Imager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UN_PwKMGGUs&ab_channel=FlukeCorporation) (about €20,000, I think). It uses an array of microphones. A search for "phased array microphones" may help.

Comment: sound frequencies don't have anything to do with visual light frequencies.  Active Sonar is a thing, these are directional microphones, not speakers.

Comment: I was thinking about attaching a camera to it and map the color of a pixel to a certain sound frequency (e.g. a red pixel on the camera will cause the speaker to emit a certain frequency)